# ServiceStack Registration Feature, what am I missing?

Tags: authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have created a solution to test the Registration feature and managed to get the tables created using the OrmLiteAuthRepository. I followed the few examples and answers here on SO build the service, however I keep getting a NotImplementedException with the following text:

```
Could not find method named Get(Register) or Any(Register) on Service RegistrationService
```

Here is the code of my Configure override in my AppHost:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
            DebugMode = true
        });


        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(SqlServerBuildDb, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

        using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
        {
            db.CreateTableIfNotExists<User>();
        }

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new BasicAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with Basic Auth
                new CredentialsAuthProvider() //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
            }));

        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
        container.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();

        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c =>
                new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
        var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
        authRepo.InitSchema();

        //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't expose the Registration Services by default, but they can be added by setting `IncludeRegistrationService=true`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[]
    {
        new BasicAuthProvider(),      //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
        new CredentialsAuthProvider() //HTML Form post with UserName/Password
    }){
        IncludeRegistrationService = true
    });
```

Which just registers the `RegistrationFeature` which you can instead register manually with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

Comment: I just added this to my sample project and I am still getting the same exception. I have also checked the /api/metadata route to confirm that the service is exposed and it does show up there. Again I feel like I am missing something really trivial here

Comment: @cornelha You shouldn't be getting the same error now that the Services are registered. Did you do a clean build? If it's still an issue can you update your question showing the HTTP Request/Response Headers (using something like Chrome WebInspector / Fiddler)?

Comment: I tracked down my issue, after setting IncludeRegistrationService to true, I sent a POST request to test and it works. I am not sure what I was expecting, but I was sending a GET request to the Route. I tested now by passing the same request twice and got an AlreadyExists errow. Thank you so much for your time